# NextJS & Strapi dockerized

Tags: docker, next.js, strapi

I am currently struggling with getting a NextJS-Application in combination with a Strapi-Application into Docker.

My project is build up like that:

> ```
> /projekt
>   /strapi
>     ...
>     Dockerfile
>   /nextjs
>    ...
>    Dockerfile
> docker-compose.yml
> ```

End - at least I think that I'm right with this - I want my docker-composed nextjs-App to build after the strapi-App is running and available for being requested.
However it seems like it does not wait long enough and fails because strapi-App is not available soon enough.

I'm also quite new to docker-compose and would also be thankful for a solution that might not work with docker-compose.yml (yet) but with individual steps that I can bake in a "build"-script to build my nextjs-App.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see your docker-compose.yml and the exact error you get when the nextjs container is being built. Otherwise, there are too many different problems that could make it seem like the strapi container is not available soon enough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you managed to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be really helpful to include your docker-compose in here.

But in case you haven't tried already:
use `depends_on` in the docker-compose file to tell the nextjs app that it depends on the other service to start first.

Like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```